# Execute a command in a specific terminal window - python

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I execute a command in a particular terminal window **that is already opened**, using python?

I can execute a command in a new terminal using python, but I want to reuse the existing terminal. And there are multiple terminals opened.
The command should run in a particular terminal.

Eg:

1. I started process A in Terminal1.
2. I kill the process A. (Now Terminal1 is idle)
3. I want to restart the process A and show the log/output of process A in Terminal1.

I'm using Ubuntu.

**Reasons to do this:**

- To keep the logs of specific commands in the same terminal.
- Separating the logs of multiple applications to different terminals.
- Maintaining the logs of specific applications in corresponding terminals
  (applications get killed and started multiple times automatically)

Comment: Python-the-language doesn't know anything about terminals; it has no constructs that can help here. There are **UNIX** constructs that can help, but they depend on you either running specific software in the terminal, or getting a handle on it some other way (as by looking up its PTY number). And frankly, none of those techniques are specific to Python -- we'd have the exact same questions we'd need answered first if you were asking how to do this in a shell script or from C.

Comment: So, let's start by backing up a little: How is your software expected to identify the specific terminal you want its output to go to? (And why aren't you just *running that software directly in the terminal in question* in the first place?)

Comment: ...if the answer is that you want the software to run in the background even when your terminal isn't open, then probably you should be writing its output to a file, and having a program running in that terminal be responsible for spooling output from that file.

Comment: ...if the answer is that you're starting your program by double-clicking on a file in a graphical interface of some kind, a place to start is discussing exactly *which* graphical interface you're using, and whether you're willing to run software that can be attached to (a la `tmux` or `screen`) inside it.

Comment: (Also, whether you only need to spool output or retrieve input as well is an important distinction).

Comment: ...if you can have software of your choice already running in and attached to the terminal in question, that means that software can just be waiting for a signal (ie. a FIFO write) performed by your GUI action or whatever else is supposed to trigger the program to run from outside the terminal, which gives you other choices as well.

Comment: Point being, there are *lots* of approaches to choose from (some of which fall under the rubric of avoiding the problem in the first place), and this question lacks sufficient details and clarifications to allow basis on which to build a specific answer.

Comment: This is my situation: I have a server and multiple related applications running on a system. I have a script that controls all these applications. My script can kill as well as start the applications automatically. The log/output of the applications are shown in separate terminals. I like to keep using the same terminal to start a specific application after it is killed by the script. **There must be some way of identifying a termial**

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of ways of identifying a terminal -- how do *you* want to do it? The same terminal running some specific other program? The terminal you started from your parent process earlier? We can't tell you what the code looks like until you tell us what you want implemented in an explicit and detailed manner.

Comment: Your "reasons to do this" don't answer any of my questions. I don't care **why** you want to do this, except inasmuch as the answer elucidates details around the surrounding environment or process tree. Everything I've asked is about "how", not "why".

Comment: (Also, parts of your description are internally contradictory: If it's a window that's already opened, how can it be "**not** any of the existing"?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, sorry for my bad English, I mean to say, it cannot choose some existing terminal at random, but a specific one. (Not "any", but specific one)

Comment: I have added an example. Hopefully, that will communicate what I need. Sorry about the language.

Comment: So, here's the general approach for this kind of problem: You start not processA, but **processA-viewer** in terminal-1. You have processA-viewer continually tail logs that processA writes (or communicate to a socket, or whatever). When you have processA running, then processA-viewer shows its output. When you exit processA, processA-viewer keeps running, waiting for a new processA to start. Make sense? (processA-viewer doesn't need to be something you write yourself -- there are several tools already available that will do the job).

Comment: That helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit kludgy and has security issues. Perhaps someone else can post a better one.

To execute a command in an open terminal window, I used [ttyecho](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/) (*see* [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/execute-command-in-remote-active-terminal) on unix.stackexchange). The security concerns with this method would appear to be similar to using `shell=True` with `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.run`.

As for selecting a particular open terminal, the linux command `ps a` lists processes that are associated with a tty and identifies the tty. I am using a Debian derivative, so my open terminals show up as processes with a 'pts/*n*' (pseudo terminal slave) tty where *n* is an integer that differentiates between different instances of open terminals. For example:

```
 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 191 tty7     Rsl+   9:12 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -aut /var/run/ligh
1049 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
1050 ttyS0    Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty ==keep-baud 115200,38400,9600,ttyS0 vt22
4254 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
4675 pts/1    Ss+    0:00 bash
4876 pts/2    Ss+    0:00 sudo /srv/xxx/main.py
4878 pts/2    S+     0:01 python3 /srv/xxx/main.py
5012 pty/0    R+     0:00 ps a
```

Assuming that you can distinguish which terminal you want to run the command in by what is already running in the terminal, you can use python code like:

```
import subprocess
r = subprocess.run(['ps', 'a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
try:
    pts = [*(line for line in r.stdout.split('\n') if searchstring in line)][0]=.split(' ')[1][4:]
except IndexError:
    pts = None
if pts:
    r2 = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'ttyecho', '-n', '/dev/pts/' + pts, command])
```

I've tested this on an rPi running kali (which uses xfce4-terminal) using python 3.5.

Comment: Btw, I find this relevant as I have not yet spent the time to learn a proper python gui and am using unix terminals as an easy proxy for a multi-windowed python gui.

Comment: Why add a second answer instead of edit your earlier (deleted) one?

Comment: ...and btw, what is `ttyecho` giving you here that just leaving out `sudo` and directly attaching stdin and stdout to the tty (opening it directly from your Python process) wouldn't do? (Yes, if the program tries to interact with `/dev/tty` that might be a problem, but most software *doesn't*... and as best I can tell, it sounds like the OP is just trying to spool logs).

Comment: I deleted the first answer because I had accidentally hit 'submit' when I had only input part of the code and didn't want anyone to be confused by the incomplete code while I was completing the answer.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment on the original question, but I would ask @Jithin if he has used the `logging` module - it provides pretty robust options, including sharing logging files between independent applications/python script instances, identification of the process making a particular log entry, etc.

Comment: ... and btw, with terminal windows and `ttyecho`, you can see the output of the different Python processes in separate terminal windows in the Linux gui while they are running as well as go back and look at their output after they have, e.g., crashed and need to be restarted. So, more debugging type uses - hence my suggestion to use the `logging` module, which easily allows messages to be sent simultaneously to *both* a terminal and a log file.

Comment: So, for future note, you can edit and undelete an answer you deleted yourself -- you don't need to start a whole new one.